# No Source App button in Google Map Callback

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I am trying to implement Google callback URL scheme, everything is working fine except that the "Source App" button that will call my app from Google Map App.

```
NSMutableString *googleMapURL = [NSMutableString   stringWithString:@"comgooglemaps-x-callback://"];
    [googleMapURL appendFormat:@"?saddr=%@",sourceAddress];
    [googleMapURL appendFormat:@"&daddr=%@",destinationAddress];
    [googleMapURL appendFormat:@"&x-success=myridepicker://?resume=true&x-source=AirApp"];

    NSLog(@"Google Map URL %@",googleMapURL);

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:googleMapURL]];
```

Complete URL from Log:`comgooglemaps-x-callback://?saddr=C+Block%2C+Noida%2C+Uttar+Pradesh&daddr=Sector+4%2C+New+Delhi%2C+Delhi%2C+India&x-success=myridepicker://?resume=true&x-source=AirApp`

[image: my_url_scheme_in_plist]

[image: no_app_name_button_here]

[image: no_app_name_here_also]

Comment: Your URI looks good to me. Possibly something wrong with your listener. Note that in ios9 Apple provided the back link by default.

Comment: Unable to figure out what's wrong with that. Hoping that someone could point out.

Comment: Hey rohit, Do u got the solution

Comment: No, didn't. Now it's default behaviour in iOS 10 whenever your apps opens an app.

Answer (score 0):

Your URLScheme needs to be: myridepicker

not: myridepicker://?resume

Comment: I've implemented the solution on more than one app. The documentation says you need to add a string you wish to use for the URL Scheme, this is supposed to contain only alpha-numeric characters. the "://" is part of the url that you need to use for the callback, it is not supposed to be used in the URL Schemes items.

Comment: Change myridepicker://?resume to myridepicker in the Plist.info file

Answer (score 0):

Just add `myridepicker` in plist.